# Function support

Tags: functional-analysis

Let be $u$ a numerical function defined over $\Omega$, with $u$ measurable, and let be $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of all open sub-sets $O_i$ of $\Omega$, such that $u=0$  almost always except on a set of measure $0$ in $O_i$. Let be $O = \cup_{i\in I}O_i$ (Then $u=0$ almost always except on a set of measure in $O$).

I need show that: If $u$ is continuos then supp $u = \Omega\setminus O = closure(\{x \in \Omega; u(x) \neq 0\})$.

How I will be able to making this?

Comment: I guess you want the topology to be second countable.

Comment: @AndréCaldas yes countable

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable base for the topology.
And let $J \subset I$ be the indexes such that
$O_j \in \mathcal{B}$ for $j \in J$.

First, we will to show that
$$
  O = \bigcup_{j \in J} O_j.
$$
It is evident that $\bigcup_{j \in J} O_j \subset O$.
On the other hand, for each $i \in I$, there is a subfamily
$\mathcal{B}_i \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that
$$
  O_i = \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{B}_i} U.
$$
Of course, if $U \in \mathcal{B}_i$, then $u = 0$ a.e. in $U$,
and therefore, $U = O_j$ for some $j \in J$.
That is,
$$
  O
  =
  \bigcup_{i \in I} O_i
  =
  \bigcup_{i \in I}
  \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{B}_i}
  U
  \subset
  \bigcup_{j \in J} O_j,
$$
as we wanted to show.

Since $J$ is countable (because $\mathcal{B}$ is),
we can conclude that $u = 0$ a.e. in $O$.
It is evident that $O$ is the largest open set such that
$u = 0$ a.e. in $O$.
Therefore, $\mathrm{supp}(u)^c \subset O$.
We have to show that $O \subset \mathrm{supp}(u)^c$.
But this is the same as showing that
$u = 0$ everywhere in $O$.
In order to show this claim, we have to assume that every
non-empty open set has strictly positive measure.

Suppose that $u(x) = \alpha \neq 0$.
Take an open interval $A$ with $x \in A$, and
$0 \not \in A$.
Then, $u^{-1}(A) \cap O$ is an open subset of $O$ where
$u \neq 0$ everywhere.
That is, $u^{-1}(A) \cap O$ has null measure.
From our assumptions, $u^{-1}(A) \cap O$ is empty.
That is, $u = 0$ everywhere in $O$.